# Distributing custom Qt plugins in OSX application bundle

Tags: macos, qt, plugins, bundle

I am building a custom application that has certain pieces of the functionality separated out into Qt plugins. This has been working quite well using `QPluginLoader` and `qobject_cast`, but up until now, I have been using a hard-coded absolute path (didn't want to complicate things before I had it working!).

I'm getting close to needing to deploy the application to other machines, so I decided to try to package the plugins up into the application bundle (I'm building this primarily for OSX). It took some research, but this is what I've come up with:

#### MyApp.pro file:

```
# ...

macx {
    plugins.path = Contents/Plugins
    plugins.files = ../PluginDir-build-desktop/libMyPlugin.dylib

    QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA += plugins
}
```

This gives a nice bundle structure that looks something like this:

```
MyApp.app
 |
 +- Contents
     |
     +- MacOS
     |   |
     |   +- MyApp
     |
     +- Plugins
     |   |
     |   +- libMyPlugin.dylib
     |
     ... other support files ...
```

So I add the plugin path to the library search paths:

#### main.cpp:

```
// ...

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QDir pluginsDir(a.applicationDirPath());
    pluginsDir.cdUp();
    pluginsDir.cd("Plugins");

    a.addLibraryPath(pluginsDir.absolutePath());

    // ...

    return a.exec();
}
```

And then try to load the plugin, like so:

```
// ...

QPluginLoader pluginLoader;
pluginLoader.setFileName("libPhotoshopPlugin.dylib");
IMyPluginInterface* plugin = qobject_cast<IMyPluginInterface*>(pluginLoader.instance());

// ...
```

Unfortunately, plugin always comes out NULL. But when I do this:

```
// ...

QPluginLoader pluginLoader;
pluginLoader.setFileName("../Plugins/libPhotoshopPlugin.dylib");
IMyPluginInterface* plugin = qobject_cast<IMyPluginInterface*>(pluginLoader.instance());

// ...
```

I get the plugin instance just fine and everything works as it should.

Why do I have to specify the path in the filename I pass to the QPluginLoader? Shouldn't it pick that up from the `QApplication` library paths? Is there something I'm just doing stupidly wrong? (I'm guessing and hoping this is more likely)

---

#### Additional note:

If I change the **plugins.path** in the **MyApp.pro** file to `Contents/MacOS`, the libMyPlugin.dylib get output next to MyApp and everything works just fine. If this is the way I should be doing it anyway, I will gladly continue doing it.

But the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/deployment-mac.html) shows the Qt plugins (qtjpeg and similar) being deployed in the `Contents/plugins` directory and a similar method for adding the directory to the `QApplication` library path.

Answer (score 1):

I store plugins in **application.app/Contents/plugins** and use the following code to obtain the plugins directory:

```
...    
#elif defined(Q_OS_MAC)
    QDir pluginsDir = QDir(qApp->applicationDirPath());
    pluginsDir.cdUp();
    pluginsDir.cd("plugins");
#else
...
```

Now you have the correct path to the plugins dir, and can load the plugin. I also have a file **qt.conf** in **application.app/Contents/Resources** with the following contents:

```
[Paths]
Plugins = plugins
```